# Could induced voltage cause interconnected fire alarms to activate?

Tags: wiring, smoke-detectors

After several weeks of the interconnected smoke alarms, I have had two momentary false alarms. I am yet to figure out why or what is causing this. Strangely they have both occurred at night causing me go down to the basement and cellar to investigate.

Question: If the interconnect wire is run in a conduit with a high amperage wire could a low voltage be induced into it causing the alarm to trigger?

Comment: Probably, usually there are regulations about wire spacing between signal wires and current / voltage wires.

Comment: What does "After several weeks of the interconnected smoke alarms" mean? Did you just recently move into a place with hard-wired alarms and you're getting false alarms? Did they recently get installed? Have you just had the false alarms over the last several weeks?

Comment: I recently installed 5 alarms and interconnected them. No false alarms for weeks then two in a week.

Comment: Can excessive heat in a room trigger a smoke alarm? My cellar is locked up all day and it gets quite hot. Im in the process of installing an exhaust fan.